# Finding digital mean using strings

Tags: c, string

As a learning exercise, I am creating a program that converts characters entered through `argv[1]` to integers. The program then finds the digital mean of the integers.

For example: `abc` would be `123`, and `1+2+3 = 6`, six being the digital mean. The first part of the program works, but I am unable to properly code the portion that finds the digital mean.

Output from `word abc` should be `123 6`; instead it is `123 150`.

---

**EDIT:** Solved!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char stra[27], strb[0];
    int str_num, str_len;
    int final = 0;

    if (argv[1][0] < 'a')
    {
        printf("!Argument missing!");
        return 0;
    }

    strcpy(stra, argv[1]);
    str_len = strlen(stra);

    for (str_num = 0; str_num < str_len; str_num++)
    {
        if (stra[str_num] <= 'z' && stra[str_num] >= 'a')
        {
            strb[str_num] = (stra[str_num] - 'a' + 1) % 9 + '0';
            if (strb[str_num] == '0')
            {
                strb[str_num] = '9';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s !Please use only the lower case!", stra);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    for (str_num = 0; str_num < str_len; str_num++)
    {
        final += strb[str_num] - '0';
    }

    printf("%s %i", strb, final);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *stra;
    char *strb;
    int str_num;
    int str_len;
    int final;
    final = 0;
    if ( (argc >= 2 && argv[1][0] < 'a') || (argc <= 1))
    {
        printf("!Argument missing!");
        return 0;
    }
    str_len = strlen(argv[1]);

    strb = (char*) malloc((str_len+1)*sizeof(char));

    for (str_num = 0; str_num < str_len; str_num++)
    {
        if (argv[1][str_num] <= 'z' && argv[1][str_num] >= 'a')
    {
        strb[str_num] = (argv[1][str_num] - 'a'+1) % 9 + '0'; //to get string with numbers from 1 to 9
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s !Please use only the lower case!",argv[1]);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    strb[str_len] = '\0' // put the end char of the string : mandatory to print it.
    for (str_num = 0; str_num < str_len; str_num++)
    {
        final += strb[str_num] - '0';  // count the sum of the numbers from 1 to 9 ?
    }
    printf("%s %i",strb,final);
    free(strb);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. I do not understand the use of malloc yet, but I have applied portions of your edited code; the program now works with desired output! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: malloc allocate memory : `char* stra = malloc(str_len * sizeof(char))` allocate  the memory for a sting of `str_len` (e.g. = 100) character exactly the same as `char stra[100];` do. It is dynamically allocated, the advantge is that you do not have to know the size of the string before compiling...

Comment: Thank you! #include<stdlib.h> takes care of the compiler warning: implicit declaration of malloc.

Comment: This answer still needs some work... `malloc` without `free`, "`* sizeof(char)`", checking for char within `'a'` to `'z'` rather than just using `isalpha` or `islower` for `<ctype.h>`...

Comment: yes... I added : `free(strb);`. using `islower`   is another way to do the check...

Comment: There's absolutely no need to cast the result of `malloc` to `char *` because in C, an implicit cast from `void *` is allowed. This can mask a more serious error if the header that declares `malloc` is not included, because the C implementation is allowed to assume that the function returns `int`, which you cast to `char *` (which may have different sizes and the conversion is implementation-defined anyway). Also, `sizeof(char)` is defined by the C standard to be 1, so it is redundant.

Comment: The headers that you have included do not actually declare `malloc` (because it is declared in `stdlib.h`).

Comment: @eharvest: If I am wrong, please point me to the relevant part of the C89 specification that disproves me, because I can reference several parts of this specification to prove me right.

Comment: my vc++ compiler does not accept the `malloc` without the cast... `sizeof(char)` is for the clarity of the code, to have all the malloc  with the same structure.

Comment: @eharvest. ***C++ IS NOT C***, you CANNOT compile all C code with a C++ compiler. C++ **DOES NOT** allow implicit conversion from `void *`, so in C++ you *need* a cast, however this question is tagged `c`, not `c++`. Also `sizeof(char)` will **NEVER** be anything except 1. That is how it is defined in the C standard. Why not multiply everything by 1? `if (argc < 1 * 1 * 1 * 1)`, or `int i = 0 * 1;`. It is redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: In C (**NOT C++**), if you explicitly cast the result of `malloc`, you are masking a *potential compiler warning* that may result in *undefined or implementationed-defined behaviour*. That is a **FACT**. Whether you chose to cast the result in C is personal choice, but I've just proven to you that it is disadvantageous to do so.

Comment: In C++ you should not be using `malloc` anyway, you should be using `new`/`new[]` and `delete`/`delete[]` instead.

Comment: i use vc++ compiler ! but i write c (and c++) programs and till now, it works fine. you are masking only other potential errors(include problem) by the cast. if no error away, no problem. the sizeof helps to have a consistent code !!!! i said it a lot of times !!!

Comment: im not talking about c++ but about c. new and delete does not interest me !!

Comment: @eharvest: You are talking about C++ because you said you couldn't compile the code with vc++. vc++ is **A C++ COMPILER** therefore C++ rules apply. I am not alone on this, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: im talking about c code compiled by vc++ which is c++ compiler. it is not an error to cast malloc but not doing it make the code non working in vc++.

Answer (score 0):

On first inspection, it seems that your program would more or less work if this were

```
strb[str_num] = (stra[str_num] - 'a') % 9 + 1
```

Also, `strb` needs to be 27 characters long as well, not 0; 0-element arrays are rather poor at holding non-zero amounts of data!

You need to check for  the argument using `argc` -- i.e.,

```
if (argc != 2)
    // complain here
```

Finally, when you're printing the results, you need to turn the ordinal numbers back into characters. Printing `strb` as a `char*` isn't going to give you `123`, but rather `^A^B^C`, not what you want. So you'll need to print those characters in a loop, adjusting each one by adding the offset of `'0'` back in.

Comment: The  % 9 - 207; is used so that only numbers 1 through 9 are used. For some reason I have to subtract 207 from the value to get the desired return, the % 9 makes sure J = 1, K = 2, et cetera.

Comment: Also, If I set strb to a length of anything other than 0, it does not work.

Comment: `strb` needs to be dynamically allocated : with the same length as the string entered as command line parameter !

Comment: The same could be said of `stra`, but I wasn't worrying about that.

Comment: in `if (argv[1] < 'a')` argv[1] is a string which can not be compared to a character, you should put : `if (argv[1][0] < 'a')`

Comment: Anyway, see my edited answer, I think I have it all worked out.

Comment: Thank you sir! Using [1][0] solved the compiler warning I was receiving. Now the only issue that remains is finding the digital mean, as edited into the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're running past the end of your buffer `strb`:

```
char strb[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strb[str_num] = (stra[str_num] - 'a') % 9 - 207;
```

The `207` is the largest problem here (aside from your off-by-one error). This line should read:

```
strb[str_num] = (stra[str_num] - 'a' + 1) % 9;
```

Comment: If I use that, I get smiley face ascii characters instead of integers as output.

Comment: ok. if you want to print strb, you need the ascii code the numbers from 1 to 9 : `strb[str_num] = (stra[str_num] - 'a' + 1) % 9 + '0';`

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, it was the     + '0'    I was missing. This works much better. Now there is only the issue of finding the digital mean.